# how to get the correct timestamp using timeago

Tags: flutter, timeago

I am trying to get the timestamp of when user commented or posted an update using timeago format but it returns a wrong time format saying an hour ago instead of a moment ago.
This is my code:

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(timeago.format(timestamp.toDate())),   
               ],
             ),
           ],
         ),
```

Timestamp code:

```
final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the exact timestamp you used?

Comment: I have updated it in the question

Comment: What is `toDate` method?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `toDate()` function?

My guess is that `toDate()` function removes hour & minute information so `2020-07-11 05:35` becomes `2020-07-11 00:00`.

Try `Text(timeago.format(timestamp))` instead.

Comment: If i use Text(timeago.format(timestamp)) and i exit the app and debug it again, it will start from a moment ago thst is the moment the app was restarted..

Comment: That is another issue you need to solve, but the answer to your current issue is to stop using the `toDate()` function. I don't know what you expected but using `DateTime.now()` means you are always going to print `a moment ago`. You need to save the time user commented to your database and provide that instead of `DateTime.now()`.

Comment: I tried your answer it throws an error at the (timestamp) this is the error: 
The argument type 'Timestamp' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.